# Redirect to "Access denied" page?

Tags: rules, users

Is there a path with which I can call the "Access denied" page?

I'm trying to implement a rule that redirects to such a page because I want to prevent users and search robots from visiting certain nodes.

This is for Drupal 6.

Comment: @Mohammad Ali Akbari's answer is the thing to do if you really do need to use a rule.  If you simply need to hide some nodes from being viewed on their own, then take a look at the [Rabbit Hole](http://drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole) module.

Comment: @MPD Thank you, I'll go with [Rabbit Hole](https://drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole). If you post your comment as an answer I can tick it as the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you simply need to add some logic to prevent nodes from being viewed on their own, there are a few well-known solutions.  If you search here, you will find the various options.

After trying a few different methods, using the [Rabbit Hole](https://drupal.org/project/rabbit_hole) module is my new preferred solution.  One, you don't need to roll your own solution in a custom module anymore.  Two, the configuration is rather flexible and supports multiple behaviors within a single site.  I don't see myself going back the method I used to promote.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to redirect to any page; you can produce the access denied page by calling [drupal_access_denied()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_access_denied/6).

Comment: Correct.  You never want to redirect away from the URL that gets denied.  The URL itself should generate the 403.  When you redirect, a 301 would get generated for the URL and then a 403 for the page you redirected to.  Same goes for making a URL 404.

Comment: I see that generating a 403 error is better. But is it possible to call this function with my rule?

Comment: You can have an action on a rule to call custom PHP.

Comment: Unfortunately when calling `drupal_access_denied();` the "Access denied" page gets displayed in addition to the normal node view.

Comment: @BernhardV, try it as adding `drupal_access_denied(); exit;`

Comment: where do you load node? `page callback` or `block`?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own action in [hook_rules_action_info()](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!rules!rules.api.php/function/hook_rules_action_info/7)
Here is sample what you can do in your_module.rules.inc file.

```
/**
 * @file your_module.rules.inc
 * Contains custom code for Rules module.
 */
/**
 * Implements hook_rules_action_info().
 */
function your_module_rules_action_info() {
  return array(
    '_your_module_access_denied' => array(
      'label' => t('Access Denied'),
      'group' => t('Nodeex Rules'),
    ),
  );
}
/**
 * Rule action _your_module_access_denied.
 */
function _your_module_access_denied() {
  return drupal_access_denied();
}
```

Comment: Also, the [content_access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access) module offers optional rules integration if you want to avoid adding custom code.